# Download files inside each Parent Node

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, treeview

Hi Guys I am looking for some ideas on how to go about downloading files inside a parent node / parent folder. The files in particular are image files with a same extension.

Basically I am following this tutorial

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Directory-Folder-structure-using-ASPNet-TreeView-control-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx

I am able to achieve a tree view structure which is great.

However, I am struggling to understand as how to go about collecting all files inside a Tree View **Parent** node so that user can download it with a single click. Perhaps loop through the parent node and grab the image files?

I am able to add a click event to the parent node using RootNodeStyle-CssClass and passing a jQuery click function as shown below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".rootNodeLevel").click(function () {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    alert("Root Node is clicked");
  });
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Better adding a js tag to this I'd think.

Comment: Thanks alexc95 tag updated